# Jenkins release-build delay

Tags: java, jenkins, eclipse-plugin

I am kicking off a release-build in Jenkins and it is causing a delay.
[image]

I am wanting the release-build to be kicked off immediately. 
Here is how I am kicking off the build:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
JenkinsJob job = new JenkinsJob("job name");
job.setCredentials(client);
PostMethod buildMethod = new PostMethod(job.getJobURL() + BUILD_WITH_PARAMETERS_URI);
client.executeMethod(buildMethod);
```

Any suggestions on how to remove this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click **Advanced...** button under **Advanced Project Options** section, and override the quiet period per job

Answer (score 1):

You can change the quiet period via the JENKINS_URL/configure link, but note that this is a global setting so it will apply to all of your Jenkins jobs.

Comment: Hmm.. is there a way to configure this for 1 jenkins job?

Comment: @ChrisBolton, yes, click **Advanced...** button under **Advanced Project Options** section, and override the quiet period per job

Comment: @Slav This is exactly what I was working for. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Slav, didn't know you could do that.